# Adding azure cloud service to azure virtual network

Tags: networking, azure, cloud

I just want to add the azure cloud service in azure virtual network. Is this possible? and how can we achieve this? Please provide me the steps to do this. As we are going to authenticating the cloud service using the on premises users using IIS domain authentication.

Comment: Hi friends, As this question is related to azure programming of how to add the cloud service to azure virtual network. you could know by the answer from "Sam Vanhoutte". So this is not off-topic i think so.

Comment: I agree with Tatas - this is 100% windows azure related

Answer (score 6):

you can do that only by editing your csfg
you need to specify the vnet and the subnet

```
<NetworkConfiguration>
<VirtualNetworkSite name="YourVirtualNetworkName" />
<AddressAssignments>
<InstanceAddress roleName="YourRoleName">
<Subnets>
<Subnet name="YourConfiguredSubnet" />
</Subnets>
</InstanceAddress>
</AddressAssignments>
</NetworkConfiguration>
```

Comment: Will the cloud service is globally accessible over internet even after moving it to azure virtual network for site to site vpn connectivity?

Comment: The cloud service is only publically exposed / accessible over the internet, if you create public endpoints for it.  IF you don't do that and you don't create RDP endpoints, the machine is not accessible from the outside.
I have set up a demo recently that exposes a Web API publically and the implementation of the api itself is reaching out over Vnet to something on prem.

Comment: NetworkConfiguration section goes under ServiceConfiguration after last Role element.